# Unable to Change ServiceDefinition file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, azure

After I have installed the **latest Azure SDK for .Net - October 2012**,I am unable to change the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file.

B'cos I need to commented out this `<!--<Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" hostHeader="www.pawloyalty.com" />-->` line.

**After compilation** It gives below mentioned message. Even though message says file has been modified outside the source editor. Actually **I did inside the source editor** (withing **vs 2010**).

[image]

**ServiceDefinition.csdef** file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  **********************************************************************************************

  This file was generated by a tool from the project file: ServiceDefinition.csdef

  Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the file is regenerated.

  **********************************************************************************************
-->
<ServiceDefinition name="PawLoyalty.Web.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2012-10.1.8">
    <WebRole name="PawLoyalty.Web" vmsize="Medium">
        <Startup priority="-2">
            <Task commandLine="startuptasks/settime.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
            <Task commandLine="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe install" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
            <Task commandLine="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe install" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
        </Startup>
        <Sites>
            <Site name="Web">
                <Bindings>
                    <Binding name="HttpIn" endpointName="HttpIn" hostHeader="www.pawloyalty.com" />
                    <Binding name="HttpsIn" endpointName="HttpsIn" hostHeader="www.pawloyalty.com" />
                </Bindings>
            </Site>
        </Sites>
        <ConfigurationSettings>
            <Setting name="Blob" />
            <Setting name="CDN" />
            <Setting name="ConnectionString" />
            <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ClientDiagnosticLevel" />
        </ConfigurationSettings>
        <Endpoints>
            <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="80" />
        </Endpoints>
        <Certificates></Certificates>
        <Imports>
            <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
            <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
            <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
            <Import moduleName="Caching" />
        </Imports>
        <LocalResources>
            <LocalStorage name="ExcelStorage" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="250" />
            <LocalStorage name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.FileStore" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
            <LocalStorage name="DiagnosticStore" sizeInMB="20000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
        </LocalResources>
    </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Why's that?

How can I change the  `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The big warning at the top of the file is your first hint.

```
<!--
  **********************************************************************************************

  This file was generated by a tool from the project file: ServiceDefinition.csdef

  Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the file is regenerated.

  **********************************************************************************************
-->
```

Basically this file is generated for you during the build based on something else.  In the case of Windows Azure its the role config Settings.

1) Close that file tab (you never change that file directly)
2) Expand the "Roles" folder
3) Double click on the role you want to change
4) in the new properties dialog, click endpoints
5) Delete the one you dont want.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually I did the above way you showed also.But My service file doesn't change. That's why I tried to do things manually.Why it is not changing when do by using UI ? And also I have to mentioned that above "generated by a tool message" is coming with latest SDK earlier It didn't.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Actually My issue was "PawLoyalty.Web.Azure" folder's status is "Read only".When I remove that status my problem vanished.Cheers.